# Failed to implement overflow hidden to DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow

Please take a look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kjKch/2/). This draggable DIV failed to stay within the dashed DIV? Tried setting `overflow: hidden` at `dropzone` but the draggable DIV still going out of it instead of hiding it?

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` to the draggable element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `containment` parameter of the draggable plugin:

```
$('#innerDropzone').draggable({
    containment: "parent"
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/kjKch/6/)

`parent` is the setting here, although you can provide a selector for any required element:

```
$('#innerDropzone').draggable({
    containment: "#dropzone"
});
```